# Deriving the Maclaurin series of $\int_{0}^{x} \frac{e^t+e^{-t}-2}{t^2}dt$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've found this question to be a bit tricky: $\int_{0}^{x} \frac{e^t+e^{-t}-2}{t^2}dt$. My first thought, knowing that $e^t = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n!}$, is to break the equation into three individual fractions and evaluate each.

The Maclaurin series of $\frac{e^t}{t^2}$ and $\frac{e^{-t}}{t^2}$ then cancel out and you can derive manually the Maclaurin series of $\frac{-2}{t^2}$ manually. Is this an effective approach or can the $\frac{-2}{t^2}$ be integrated into the existing Maclaurin series to find an answer? Is there a more effective way to do this without breaking it up?

Comment: breaking it up? you calculate the series for e^t and e^-t and than add them then minus 2 and divide that by t^2 and than integrate last

Comment: Will the addition of $e^t$ and $e^{-t}$ not cancel out? The only difference between their Maclaurin series is that $e^{-t}$ has a negative out front.

Comment: No they won't you need to check this first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $f(0)=0.$ Moreover $$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \frac{e^t+e^{-t}-2}{t^2}dt\implies f'(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{x^2}.$$

Now, $$e^x+e^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=2+x^2+2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}.$$ Thus

$$\frac{e^x+e^{-x}-2}{x^2}=1+2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2(n-1)}}{(2n)!}.$$

Now, it should be easy to get the MacLaurin series of $f.$